# PHP: What does `array(&$this)` mean?

Tags: php, this

In PHP, I would like to know what `array(&$this)` means.

Comment: It means you're using a PHP4 script :)  PHP 5 will *always* pass references of objects, so it's not necessary to denote it as a reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a construct that initializes an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) which contains one element: a [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php) to the object the array is initialized in. Inside every class, you can refer to the "current" instance using [`$this`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: also one should note that this construct (`array(&$something)`) can be used as a workaround to use the "pass by reference" to a function that has default parameters. There is a big discussion going on about this in the comments section of the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 6):

Its PHPs [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) construction. Typically this means that a reference to the parameter is passed to the function instead of a copy of the value, so that modifications inside the function affect the object.

Comment: and &$this refers to the array ?

Comment: @Jasper: Sorry, sorting out the details took longer than I expected.

Comment: @Zaidar: No, `&$this` refers to "the current object" - the current instance of the class the code is in.

Comment: There is no "passing" here.

Answer (score 0):

This is creating an array with a single element. The element is a reference to the object from which it is executed it. For more information see the documentation on [passing by reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)